# Multiple threads, counting number of running threads

Tags: java, processing

I'm building an RL ai for checkers (so ill be running a lot of different games), and each thread will run a game separately on its own. Im trying to limit the amount of running threads. So if the amount of running threads is less than a certain amount (`threadAmount`): then create a new thread and run a new game, else: don't do anything and wait.

```
for (int i = 0; i < population.size(); i++) {
    int runningThreads = 0;
    for (int j = i; j < population.size(); j++) if (population.get(j).gameOver == false) runningThreads++; //for each running thread, add 1 to runningThreads
    if (runningThreads < threadAmount){ //threadAmount == max # of threads
      population.get(i).gameOver = false;
      Thread newThread = new Thread(population.get(i));
      newThread.start();
      println("\tnew thread started | "+runningThreads);
      delay(100);
    }
    else{
      i--; //retry this 
    }
  }
```

The problem is that it just creates all the threads willy nilly, the `println` shows "new thread started | 0" 25 times and the `runningThreads` var doesn't seem to increase in the for loop at all, and just stays at 0. Unsure what to do :/, but I know this is Processing and that its not thread safe so im ready to pull some fancy smancy stuff to get it done.

Comment: Your code is not clear, please use proper brackets. You use no brackets for second for loop, you should do it. Incrementing integer value doesn't work well with multi threading approach, you can better declare a global List<Threads> and before starting any thread, add the thread to this container. if any thread exits, remove it from this or you can check if thread is running, thus you get the current live thread count. I think this will help you to correctly measure thread counts.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the Processing language?  If not, please remove the "processing" tag, because it is inappropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, these are your requirements:

- Run each game in a separate `Thread`.
- Never allow more than `n` games (or `Thread`s) to run at the same time.
- If the maximum number of games are currently running, wait until one or more finish then run the new game.

The last bullet point is not entirely clear. It could mean the game should be queued for execution *or* it could mean the scheduling `Thread` should block until "space" becomes available.

In the first case (queuing) this can be easily solved by using an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) configured to have no more than `n` threads. Any tasks submitted while all threads are busy will be queued until a thread becomes available.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadAmount);
for (Runnable r : population) {
    executor.execute(r);
}
executor.shutdown(); // If you won't be using it later
```

This also has the added benefit of reusing `Thread` instances rather than creating a new `Thread` for each game.

Comment: This is the sensible approach.  There is no need for the OP to reinvent a bounded thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, here is a code sample but its in c#, i have no java code currently. But it should work similarly

```
List<Task> lTask = new List<Task>();

Worker w = new Worker(msg);
Task t = new Task(() => w.DoWork());
            t.Start();
            lTask.Add(t);`.
```

I keeping added tasks to the global list. ANd in a timer, I periodically check if anyone of the task (aka thread) expires,

```
foreach(Task t in lTask)
                {
                    if (!t.Status.Equals(TaskStatus.Running))
                    {
                        // This thread is running... do whatever you do
                    }

                }
```

Thats my way to work with muti threads, and keep log of their life.